# sqlite nested query with division

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I'm a bit new to SQL and am wondering the best way to do this. basically one query returns the denominator, and the outer query needs to return the numerator/denominator as a percent. the same tables are essentially used for each statement.

```
create table games(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    category   TEXT NOT NULL
);

create table game_sets(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    theme_id  integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO games (id, name, category)
VALUES (1, "star wars", "top game"),
(2, "pokemon", "top game"),
(3, "zelda", "top game"),
(4, "crazy cats", "sucky game");

INSERT INTO game_sets(id, name, theme_id)
VALUES (1, "star wars set 1", 1),
(2, "star wars set 2", 1),
(3, "star wars set 3", 1),
(4, "pikachu set 1", 2),
(5, "narf set 1", 4),
(6, "narf set 2", 4),
(7, "narf set 1", 4),
(8, "narf set 1", 4),
(9, "narf set 1", 4),
(10, "narf set 1", 4);



CREATE VIEW top_games AS
SELECT id, name
FROM games
WHERE category ='top game';

--i hard coded 200 below, but it needs to be dynamic

select top_games.name as theme, printf("%.2f", cast(count(game_sets.name)as float)/200) as num_sets_percent from top_games
join game_sets
where top_games.id = game_sets.theme_id
group by top_games.id
order by num_sets desc
limit 2;

--below here is the number i need for the first query to divide
--i have it hard coded as 4 b/c 4 total sets in the game_sets table, but it needs to be dynamic with this query

(select count(game_sets.name) as num_sets from game_sets
join top_games
where top_games.id = game_sets.theme_id) as divide_by_this
```

output:
star wars, .3 (because 3 star wars sets out of 10 total sets and star wars is a top game)
pokemon, 0.1 (because 1 pokemon set out of 10 total sets and is also a top set)
and last we limited it to only the 2 top sets so the zelda set doesn't show up.

Comment: So put another `COUNT` instead of your hard-coded value.  What seems to be the problem?

Comment: if i do that it's the numerator and denominator are the same(ie. 10/10) due to the group by and limit.  what  i need is the denominator to be the sum of all sets(not limited to top 10).

Comment: I think now I got it. You need grand total and individual sub-totals. You will need to calculate the grand total in a subquery and then `JOIN` it to the main query.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the desired result to your question.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks just did that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQLite 3.25.0+ you can use window functions:

```
select distinct
  g.name,
  1.0 * count(g.id) over (partition by g.id) / count() over () num_sets_percent
from game_sets s left join top_games g
on s.theme_id = g.id
order by num_sets_percent desc
limit 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n98TDRuyPHwZPqNsioS8PC/5).
Results:

```
| name      | num_sets_percent |
| --------- | ---------------- |
| star wars | 0.3              |
| pokemon   | 0.1              |
```

Comment: thanks this is close, but i have to query the view (top_games) created only. so it's the sets in the view, divided by the total number of sets (not in the view)

Comment: thanks! that does work.  the directions say only an inner join may be used, but that seems crazy. is there any way to do this without the left join?

Comment: Joining the view top_games to the table game_sets with an inner join would result in only the matched rows, so no it would not work. My previous code without the view, used an inner join and it worked.